# ArcGIS desktop 10.3: Is it possible to have all popups showing at once when exporting/printing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, html-popup

I'm very new to ArcGIS software, and I need a map to look like this map I drew on in MS Paint, with multiple popups showing.  Is there any easy, user-friendly way of going about doing that with ArcGIS 10.3?  I need to able to print the map with all the popups displayed.

[image]